# PHP mail function causing error

Tags: php

I am working on setting up an automated email response via my PayPal IPN Script, however the following code causes paypal's sandbox to fail.

```
// PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED!

$email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$password = mt_rand(1000, 9999);

$to      = $email;
$subject = 'Download Area | Login Credentials';
$message = '

Thank you for your purchase

Your account information
-------------------------
Email: '.$email.'
Password: '.$password.'
-------------------------

You can now login at http://yourdomain.com/PayPal/';
$headers = 'From:noreply@yourdomain.com<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function(){try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l,b=document.getElementsByTagName("script");l=b[b.length-1].previousSibling;a=l.getAttribute('data-cfemail');if(a){s='';r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})();
/* ]]> */
</script>' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Is there something simplistically wrong with it, or is there a deeper cause for the script to cause an error. Keep in mind, i am new to this, and this is code that i copy and pasted from http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-paypals-instant-payment-notification-with-php--net-3271.

Also, does the from email i use have to be located on the same server i am using to host the script?

the email is removed to avoid giving out personal information.

Comment: Please, please, please do not send any password as plaintext in an email.

Comment: For reference, the IPN Sandbox does not tell me what the error is, all i know is that it isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

What is this?

```
$headers = 'From:noreply@yourdomain.com<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function(){try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l,b=document.getElementsByTagName("script");l=b[b.length-1].previousSibling;a=l.getAttribute('data-cfemail');if(a){s='';r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})();
/* ]]> */
</script>' . "\r\n";
```

You can't have HTML or JavaScript in your mail headers. Take that out ads that is what is probably causing your errors.

```
$headers = 'From:noreply@yourdomain.com';
```

Comment: love to know what the op put that there

Comment: As i said in my post, i just took the code from a tutorial website. I am not good with PHP. Also, i have no intention of using the password,  i just have it there because i never got rid of it. I will try out what you said John.

Comment: Update: The above solution allowed the IPN to be successfully sent, but as state in the OP, do i need to have the FROM:Email need to be hosted on the same server?

Comment: So the IPN sent successfully, but i have not received any emails. I have one for VERIFIED And INVALID responses from the IPN

Comment: There could be lots of reasons for this. Start by trying to send the email from different addresses, some on the server, some not. And to different addresses, some on the server, some not. If you receive some and not others then you know the mail code works. Then search this site for how to keep your mail from getting flagged as spam to improve your delivery rate.

Comment: My updated code is found here: http://pastebin.com/EAGymQkw. This still seems to not send emails to the address i tried. To and from were both changed with no luck.